# Java variables across methods

Tags: java, variables

I'm making a basic text editor, and I have 2 methods the first one is triggered when a user click 'Open' and it prompts the user to pick a file and it opens the file fine.  I just want to access the same file path which is in a variable in the method that is triggered when the user clicks save.  My methods are public, Iv'e tried accessing it through a class, still no.  Please help!
Code:

```
public void open(){
    try{
        //Open file
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    String haha = file.getPath();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        text.append(line + "\n");
    }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){

    }
}

public void save(){
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.filePath));

        bw.write(text.getText());

        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you define the variable containing the file path outside the scope of the method? I.e. is the variable defined in your class?

Comment: Not a question that deserves negative vote, but still the OP needs to paste his code and errors, if any.

Comment: Ok give me a min to paste, and iv'e declared it outside the methods yes.

Comment: It won't work because when I try to set the variable outside the method I need to access information that is in the method, and the method is public.

Answer (score 1):

Store the full path of file in one variable, & use that variable where you want: only condition is that your variable must be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would have an instance of `TextEditor` that holds the data. The methods `open()`, `display()`, `save()` would be present in the `TextEditor` and uses the state of `TextEditor` (e.g. the file name) to perform their operation. The UI event handlers present in the `Controller` class would have access to the `TextEditor` instance which is the model and invokes appropriate actions on the instance (like open, display, save etc.,).